# Spring State Machine : is it safe to user multiple actions on transition?

Tags: java, spring-statemachine

Version of Spring state machine : 1.2.14

Spring State Machine allows to configure a transition with multiple actions (multiple .action() calls).

I use this to define "atomic" actions i can reuse along transitions, or have different behaviour depending on the transition.

I suddenly ended to ask if order is preserved. It seems so, according to org.springframework.statemachine.config.configurers.AbstractTransitionConfigurer :

```
private final Collection<Function<StateContext<S, E>, Mono<Void>>> actions = new ArrayList<>();
```

Here my questions :

1. But the field is defined as Collection so can i really count on order?
2. Using multiple actions should not count on order?
3. Is it a bad practice to use multiple actions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's OK to use multiple actions, and the order is preserved.

Note that the concrete type is an `ArrayList` - both in the transition configurer you've mentioned *and* in the state configurer. Actions can be attached to either transitions or states.

meaning that the order is according to the order that you've configured the actions.

Comment: Thx for your answer. Can i really count on the order as the type is a Collection and not a List? Maybe the developpers chose Collection on purpose?

Comment: The concrete type is what determines the actual behavior